# My text and picture aren't aligned in minipage environment

Tags: graphics, vertical-alignment, minipage

My image and text aren't aligned. The image is further down. How can I change that?

[image]

```
\begin{minipage}{0.6\textwidth} 
some text
\end{minipage} %
\hspace{.1cm}
\begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth} 
\setspace
\includegraphics[scale=0.39]{Images/Verhuellungsverbot ja.png}
\end{minipage}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have not provided a usable example, and the image shown is clearly not generated by the code shown, however

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx,setspace}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{0.6\textwidth} 
some text some text some text some text some text some text
some text some text some text some text some text some text
some text some text some text some text some text some text
some text some text some text some text some text some text
some text some text some text some text some text some text
some text some text some text some text some text some text
\end{minipage} %
\hspace{.1cm}
\begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth} 
% no idea what this is \setspace
\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{example-image}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Produces

[image]

with vertically centered boxes with a word-space and .1cm in between.

You can top align the boxes and flush them to the page margins

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx,setspace}
\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.6\textwidth} 
some text some text some text some text some text some text
some text some text some text some text some text some text
some text some text some text some text some text some text
some text some text some text some text some text some text
some text some text some text some text some text some text
some text some text some text some text some text some text
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\textwidth} 
\vspace{-.5em}
\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{example-image}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't show my text because I will be checked for plagiarism. But thank you for your help!!

Comment: @IAmLost no one needs to see your original document, but you should always include an example in the question. As you are relatively new here, I guessed one this time, but your question could have been closed as unclear.